# PayPal API credentials for sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement recurring payments with PayPal in PHP. I found [this example](https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Recurring-Payment-example), which I'm looking into, but I need some API credentials. I created a PayPal sandbox account, and from there I created a merchant account. I'm trying to get the API credentials for that sandbox merchant account to replace the values in the example, but I can't find where. All the guides I find point to non-existant parts of the sandbox user interface. Does anyone know where I can find the API credential details for sandbox merchant accounts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>I'm beginning to</strike> **I loathe PayPal.**  Spent an hour on their site looking for this, only to find it here on SO (works as of  Oct-2014):

Live: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run

Test: https://sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run

Answer (score 6):

To get API credentials in sandbox you must use the API Credentials menu in sandbox itself, instead of logging into the sandboxed account.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/7sDnu.png]

Comment: This section will only contain API credentials if you chose to create a 'preconfigured account' via https://developer.paypal.com > Test accounts.

Comment: The api credentials are only generated when using an test account located in "united states" and of type "seller". I tried using "Germany" and no credentials were generated.

Comment: this is for old sandbox (Obsolete)