# Where in the new PayPal Developer account can I get API credentials?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Does anyone know where in the new PayPal Developer (Beta) account I can get API Credentials (NOT REST API Credentials). There used to be a link in the left nav of the old Developer site as you can see in this post [PayPal API credentials for sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769876/paypal-api-credentials-for-sandbox) The exact information I'm looking for is "API Username", "API Password" and either "API Certificate file" or "API Signature". In regular PayPal accounts you can get this info through a link on the My Account > Profile page (this page: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s141/sh/ec645865-2d05-4a7e-99b2-8f616d20384f/74642340d102c67e0e250806d3fed007) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the steps that Chirag B provided not working for some accounts, due to some issues within the new developer site.  Those are the correct steps that Chirag listed, but if they do not show there is another work around.  That would be to log into the actual test sandbox seller account that you are wanting the credentials for and go to your profile and request/view your API credentials there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried logging into the sandbox account and going to My Account > Profile however the link that I usually use to generate an API signature and or certificate file isn't there. Here's a screen cap https://www.evernote.com/shard/s141/sh/ec645865-2d05-4a7e-99b2-8f616d20384f/74642340d102c67e0e250806d3fed007 As you can see there's no mention of the API at all on the page :(

Comment: What type of an account is it?  What country is the account set up under, and is the accuont verified?  If you can provide the test sandbox seller email address, or the merchant id number for the account I can pull it up on my side and take a look at it.

Comment: It's a business account, country is US and it has been verified. The email ID is nikita.makeyev3@sumeffect.com Here's a screen cap of the details of the sandbox account I'm using in case you want to take a peek. https://www.evernote.com/shard/s141/sh/abe0434e-95d4-40b5-ad25-47f61a07c142/b6804e6c384799c8c188f442628b6562 Thanks for helping me with this :)

Comment: Can you try logging into the seller account now and see if you can see these credentials or request them now.  If that still doesn't work, try using this URL https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-api-access after you have logged into the seller account.

Comment: Woot! I logged into the sandbox seller account again and I can now see the "API Access" link I was looking for earlier. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Kita i think it didn't show signature earlier because you didn't requested API credentials. Now you already requested, i guess from now on you will not need to login to account, You can now directly view it from Main screen of sandbox as i suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Click the arrow to the left of your required Sandbox account(i.e Expand the row).

Click on Profile -> API Credentials tab.
This will show the API Credentials.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. When I go to that section I only see the username and password. The signature is blank, there's no mention of the certificate file and I don't see any way to generate the signature. Here's a screen cap https://www.evernote.com/shard/s141/sh/b6770250-8eaf-43c5-a955-d1ff75501d3a/38e6c646667995612399017ff0678d97 Do you happen to know how to get either the signature or the certificate file in addition to username & password?